# Many-to-many on same table

Tags: mysql

Funny that I've never come across this yet!

It never occurred to me that one could have a "many to many" relationship on one table- until I started working on a system where users can "friend" each other (social networking).

A standard lookup table, at least in the way that I'm used to using it, isn't appropriate here. Lets keep it simple:

User table has "id" and "name" column.

User_relationship table has "uid1" and "uid2", representing users that are "friends" or "buds" or "pals" or "whatever else".

It becomes apparent pretty quick what the problem here is- uid1 and uid2 are the same data type from the same column of the same table, meaning that unique keys become flawed.

E.g.:
uid1 = 1
uid2 = 2

Is the same as:

uid1 = 2
uid2 = 1

And therefore could return 2 records, or 0 records if the query is performed wrong.

In the spirit of designing a table well, I don't want to have to scan the entire table twice to check for existing values.

Is there some sort of trick for handling this? This is a design question that has never occurred to me, and it irks me because I know that there's some simple trick to make it work.

Before you ask, I haven't tried anything yet, because I already see that my favorite way of relating things (lookup tables) is insufficient for my needs here, and I need some help- I can't find anything on SO or Google :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *can* have a M-M relationship between a table and itself using the same "joiner table" method used for any other M-m relationship.

Comment: You obviously can have m-m within one table- where users relate to each other. Think facebook or myspace or anything else, many users can have many friends as users- that is a many-to-many relationship on the user table itself, not between two tables.
@Umbrella I'm asking how to relate users to each other- what is the way to do it to avoid having duplicate entries. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Try adding in some code.  What is the SELECT that is giving you trouble?

Comment: This isn't a question of what to select, it's a question of duplicating entries. Say for instance user1 tries to friend user2 at the same time, or some other fringe case where both entries could exist that represent the same relationship.

Comment: Can't you add a `UNIQUE KEY` to your joiner table?

Comment: More to the point, What challenge would a (1,2),(2,1) duplication cause you?  That cannot be answered without seeing what you're trying.

Comment: 1) Does UNIQUE KEY cover reverse value sets? I don't think it does.
2) It scratches in the back on my mind that having duplicate sets of values that represent the same data is bad design. Say something happens between the first delete and the second delete, and half of the value set is still in there? It screams pain to me later on. Are you opposed to @Denis's comment about uid1 is always less than uid2? That seems like it'd always work.

Comment: The question of reverse sets depends on whether you want to allow relationships to be unidirectional, or keep unidirectional meta data.  This is apparently not decided yet.  That said, Denis' solution for enforcing single-pair-bi-directional relationships looks good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> meaning that unique keys become flawed.
>
> ```
> uid1 = 1 uid2 = 2
> ```
>
> Is the same as:
>
> ```
> uid1 = 2 uid2 = 1
> ```

Nope, it's not.

On Facebook, for instance, I've a number of customers who sent requests to become "friends" that I never accepted... Since they're mere acquaintances.

Along the same lines, I might have marked a few people as best friends, and they didn't reciprocate, or vice versa. Or perhaps I'm ignoring a few and they are not.

Basically, there's a lot more information in a `(uid1, uid2)` tuple than mere IDs.

Make sure that you never need to deal with situations like these before deciding to add e.g. a `uid1 < uid2` constraint on your table.

Comment: Yes, but adding in more data about the relationship is outside the scope of this question, I'm simply asking about the immediate relationship (leaving "confirmed" friendships and friendship type like "best" out of it). I do really like the constraint of having uid1 < uid2 though... is that a bad thing??

Comment: Well, if you don't think you need two rows per relationship, the constraint is a good way to enforce that no unneeded rows get inserted -- you're guaranteed that all tuples will be unique. Note that you'll still need to check both columns to fetch all relationships, though.

Comment: But then, long term, you'll end up storing whichever meta information will creep up, no matter how hard you try to avoid it. So methinks you ought to use two rows per relationship. X is friend with Y is, simply put, not equivalent to Y is friend with X. Even if we pretend it is in many social relationships.

Comment: Hmmm.. thats a valid point. I just now understood why you talked about friendships that you never accepted. You're right. This seems like the best solution.

Comment: Think also about how a user might tag or add personal meta data to their friend, I think each user needs their own entry for a friendship to do this nearly, also makes finding current users friends straightforward

Comment: I'm curious how you would enforce this constraint in the table.  Is there a DDL syntax for that, or would it be done in the application layer?

Comment: @Umbrella: `create table ([columns defs, etc...], check (uid1 < uid2));` -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Comment: If you read carefully docs link to which you posted In MySql **The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines**, so it won't work. See it an [action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8c57/1). **The only** way to enforce this kind of constraint is by using `BEFORE TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 16):

If the relationship you're describing is symmetrical, as in "Bob is a friend of Joe" means "Joe is also a friend of Bob", then you can make sure in your code that the smaller of the 2 user IDs goes on the first column, and the larger one goes on the second column. This constraint pretty much ensures that the records in your lookup table will be unique. It also means that when you're performing a lookup, you usually have to search both columns.

For example, if you were trying to get all of Bob's friends, you would have to query for records that have Bob's ID in either column. This leads to a bit more code and possibly an impact on performance.

If the relationship can be asymmetrical, as in "Bob is a friend of Joe" does not necessarily mean "Joe is also a friend of Bob", then you need 2 entries for every pair of users: Bob - Joe and Joe - Bob. This means that your lookup table will contain twice as many entries and also that your site is very stalker-friendly :D Of course, you can still choose to apply this system even though your relationship is symmetrical.

Using this method, if you want to get all of Bob's friends you just have to select the records with Bob's ID in the first column. It is possible that this might mean faster lookups and less code for you to write, but again, it means you're taking up more room in your database.

Comment: Of course, people's data wont be supplied to people who they haven't listed as a friend. :D

Answer (score 2):

This is not that uncommon.

Typically what is done is that there is a table, as in most many-many relationships that consists of two columns, each being an id, of the two tables, that make up the primary key.

As you stated userId1 and userId2.  Attributes, if necessary, can be added to the relationship (such as classification of friendship).

When user 1 befriends user 2, there are typically two inserts, (1,2) and (2,1).

Same sort of thing with a defriending, there needs to be two deletes.

You could end up with a user having himself as a friend, and that might be critical to the actual workings of the system.  If a user can only view photos of his friends, then if he is not a friend to himself, some systems might not allow him to see his own photos.

It is very dependent upon how the application is written on top of the database.

Comment: Ooh that's interesting. So are you saying that it's NOT bad to have two versions of the same relationship? Doesn't that mean having a table that is literally 2x as big as you would want? Also, where do you know that that is the "typical" practice? (just curious)

Comment: I think this is the approach I would take, while both columns hold user ids, I'd have first column as friender, second column as friendee.

Comment: It had occurred to me, though funny enough it was this exact scenario that prompted me to start asking this question. It seems to me that those are "technically" duplicate entries, and that that's a no-no. I'm not any sort of DBA though by any means... what about @Denis's comment on constraining the columns so that uid1 is always smaller than uid2? You could do that in the insertion code. Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what others have said, it's isn't a bad idea to have 2 inserts for a relationship (1:2 and 2:1). This actually helps to expand some of the features which are commonly found in modern social networks. Some cases of practical use that I can think of is description of relationship or other attributes. While individuals remain friends they maintain different setting towards each other. In 1:2 relationship Bob is following Joe's updates and has him on best friend list (add bff column), while in 2:1 Joe doesn't have Bob on bff list and doesn't care to follow his posts (following column).