# Is it possible to implement Many-To-Many association on the same entity/table using ecto

Tags: elixir, many-to-many, associations, ecto

I have a User table with a unique primary key, and would like to setup a `many-to-many` association to another `User` entity in order to achieve a "social network" kind of thing. From this [Many-to-many on same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128472/many-to-many-on-same-table) i understand this is possible, but how can i structure the `ecto` schema for the same?

Currently using a `join_through` as [described here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/associations.html#many-to-many) with a schema with some extra fields to further define the association such as a flag `blocked` in case a user blocks another, but i had an issue setting up the `has_many` on the join table since both scenarios point to the same `User` schema. till i began to wonder whether this is really possible with ecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surely possible, you just need to instruct *Ecto* how to get to the respective fields.

For migrations

```rb
create table(:users) do
  add(:name, :string)
end

create table(:friendship) do
  add(:me_id, references("users"))
  add(:friend_id, references("users"))
end
```

And the respective schemas

```rb
schema "users" do
  field(:name, :string)

  many_to_many(:users, User,
    join_through: "friendship",
    join_keys: [me_id: :id, friend_id: :id]
  )
end

  schema "friendship" do
    field(:me_id, :integer)
    field(:friend_id, :integer)
  end
```

You might do the following

```rb
iex|1> Repo.insert! %User{name: "john"}
iex|2> Repo.insert! %User{name: "mary"}
iex|3> Repo.insert! %Friendship{me_id: 1, friend_id: 2}
```

Resulting in

```rb
iex|4> Repo.one(from u in User, 
...|4>   where: [id: 1], preload: [:users])

%User{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
  id: 1,
  name: "john",
  users: [
    %User{
      __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
      id: 2,
      name: "mary",
      users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank Aleksei, this really came in handy, turns out they way i had my join table was not following a normalized manner, hence the problems.

Comment: just a follow-up question,

In a scenario where i would need to have a single unique `Friendship` record between any two `peers`, in such a way that, if for example `peer_1` marked `peer_2` as a friend meaning a `friendship` is established. 
Is it possible to have a constraint on the `friendship` so its the only one that exists? in that if `peer_2` decides to mark `peer_1` as a friend, then a constraint violation is raised.

I've been trying to set this up but does not seem to work, currently fetching for existing `friendship` before reaching the db, any thoughts on this?
Thanks

Comment: This is extremely counter-intuitive in the first place. If I list you as a friend, you probably would be surprised when you will be denied from listing me as a friend. But you might create a calculated field as concat(ids) or like and make it unique.

Comment: Yeah, i see how it might be an issue, the idea behind this thought is to have common items for a given `friendship` either from `peer_1`  or `peer_2` a good example would be `messages`, with the current setup i would have messages for each friendship that exists, where's these messages no matter from peer1 or peer2 are common to both ends of the association. In such a way, if i fetched for a `friendship`, i can also preload the `messages` to that friendship without having them filtered from only one peer ie the one that recorded friendship in the first place.

Comment: It does not work that way, though. I might have listed you as a friend while you might have hated me :) For messages, you might have messages `me→you` and `you→me` linked to _sender_ and preload both.

Comment: Mmmhhh...interesting, i hadn't thought of it that way. Thanks for the insight. ;)